# gcc generate `call` to the address of the next instruction

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm compiling the next code using `cc -g -O0 -m32`:

```
void f() {
    int l;
    short s;
    char c;

    l = 0xdeadbeef;
    s = l;
    c = l;

    printf("l = 0x%x (%d bits)\n", l, sizeof(l) * 8);
    printf("s = 0x%x (%d bits)\n", s, sizeof(s) * 8);
    printf("c = 0x%x (%d bits)\n", c, sizeof(c) * 8);
}
```

What's the purpose of the following lines?

```
   0x00001e89 <+9>: call   0x1e8e <f+14>
   0x00001e8e <+14>:    pop    %eax
   0x00001e8f <+15>:    lea    0xe8(%eax),%ecx
```

When I disassemble using gdb

```
(gdb) disassemble f
Dump of assembler code for function f:
   0x00001e80 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x00001e81 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x00001e83 <+3>: push   %ebx
   0x00001e84 <+4>: push   %edi
   0x00001e85 <+5>: push   %esi
   0x00001e86 <+6>: sub    $0x3c,%esp
   0x00001e89 <+9>: call   0x1e8e <f+14>
   0x00001e8e <+14>:    pop    %eax
   0x00001e8f <+15>:    lea    0xe8(%eax),%ecx
   0x00001e95 <+21>:    mov    $0x20,%edx
   0x00001e9a <+26>:    movl   $0xdeadbeef,-0x10(%ebp)
   0x00001ea1 <+33>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%esi
   0x00001ea4 <+36>:    mov    %si,%di
   0x00001ea7 <+39>:    mov    %di,-0x12(%ebp)
   0x00001eab <+43>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%esi
   0x00001eae <+46>:    mov    %esi,%ebx
   0x00001eb0 <+48>:    mov    %bl,-0x13(%ebp)
   0x00001eb3 <+51>:    mov    -0x10(%ebp),%esi
   0x00001eb6 <+54>:    mov    %ecx,(%esp)
   0x00001eb9 <+57>:    mov    %esi,0x4(%esp)
   0x00001ebd <+61>:    movl   $0x20,0x8(%esp)
   0x00001ec5 <+69>:    mov    %eax,-0x18(%ebp)
   0x00001ec8 <+72>:    mov    %edx,-0x1c(%ebp)
   0x00001ecb <+75>:    call   0x1f5a
   0x00001ed0 <+80>:    mov    -0x18(%ebp),%ecx
   0x00001ed3 <+83>:    lea    0xfc(%ecx),%edx
   0x00001ed9 <+89>:    mov    $0x10,%esi
   0x00001ede <+94>:    movswl -0x12(%ebp),%ecx
   0x00001ee2 <+98>:    mov    %edx,(%esp)
   0x00001ee5 <+101>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
   0x00001ee9 <+105>:   movl   $0x10,0x8(%esp)
   0x00001ef1 <+113>:   mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
   0x00001ef4 <+116>:   mov    %esi,-0x24(%ebp)
   0x00001ef7 <+119>:   call   0x1f5a
   0x00001efc <+124>:   mov    -0x18(%ebp),%ecx
   0x00001eff <+127>:   lea    0x110(%ecx),%edx
   0x00001f05 <+133>:   mov    $0x8,%esi
   0x00001f0a <+138>:   movsbl -0x13(%ebp),%ecx
   0x00001f0e <+142>:   mov    %edx,(%esp)
   0x00001f11 <+145>:   mov    %ecx,0x4(%esp)
   0x00001f15 <+149>:   movl   $0x8,0x8(%esp)
   0x00001f1d <+157>:   mov    %eax,-0x28(%ebp)
   0x00001f20 <+160>:   mov    %esi,-0x2c(%ebp)
   0x00001f23 <+163>:   call   0x1f5a
   0x00001f28 <+168>:   mov    %eax,-0x30(%ebp)
   0x00001f2b <+171>:   add    $0x3c,%esp
   0x00001f2e <+174>:   pop    %esi
   0x00001f2f <+175>:   pop    %edi
   0x00001f30 <+176>:   pop    %ebx
   0x00001f31 <+177>:   pop    %ebp
   0x00001f32 <+178>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a trick to generate position independent code. You can see the next instruction is a `pop %eax` which will fetch the return address from the stack. Of course the return address is the address of the `pop` itself hence this gets the absolute address of the instruction so it can be used as a base for accessing things relative to the code.

It is immediately used to fetch the first argument for the first `printf` call, the literal format string. You can see that `ecx` is loaded based on `eax` on line `+15` and then `ecx` is written on the stack at line `+54` in the first argument slot as per the calling convention.

The reference point is also stored at `-0x18(%ebp)` on line `+69`. Like for the first `printf`, it is then reused for the subsequent format strings, see lines `+83` and `+127`.

Comment: `%eax` is loaded with the instruction absolute address = `0x00001e8e` (or `<f+14>`). What should appear in address  `0x00001e8e+ 0xe8`? i.e. why is the content of that address is loaded into `%ecx`? (by the instruction on address `<+15>`

Comment: Sorry, I missed how the code uses it. See updated answer. Note, using `gcc -S` should produce a more readable code, where you can even see the format strings being referenced.